# EasyPHP and windows 8

Tags: php, easyphp

Need some help with Windows 8 installation.

I was able to install EasyPHP on the Windows 8 Consumer Preview, but when I try to visit "http://127.0.0.1/" to access my local webpages, I get a

> Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage

error and it doesn't work in any other browser.

Comment: Have you tried using a later build, such as the Release Preview?

Comment: Take look -> http://www.easyphp.org/introduction.php

Comment: Yes, for sure. It 's running and it use to work normaly on Windows 7.

Comment: I'm using the build 9200 that was released for testing on Wenesday.